# How to copy a row of a Mat to another Mat's column in OpenCv?

Tags: opencv

I have two Mat:

```
A:
size(1,640)
B:
size(640,480)
```

I want to copy A to B's first column so I use `A.copyTo(B.col(0))`.But this failed. How to do it?

Comment: correct answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613787/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You were on the right track! `Mat:col` is the matching tool to use :)

But beware, simply assigning one col to another one won't work as you may expect it, because `Mat:col` just creates a new matrix header for the matrix column you specified and no real copy of the data.

**Example code:**

```
B.col( 0 ) = A.col( 0 ); // won't work as expected

A.col( 0 ).copyTo( B.col(0) ); // that's fine
```

Comment: The question was not about "assigning one col to another one". It was about assigning one row  to another column.

Comment: @Vit actually its similar..  A.col(0).copyTo(B.row(0));